# No image found after uploading it with Muller

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am making a small script to upload a photo and save it to local storage. I'm using Express and Muller for this.

I have an html page with an upload field (see below). As soon as I press the 'upload photo' button he sends the photo to the endpoint '/upload'. Here he should save the photo on my computer under the name 'image.jpg' only when it comes in the post the 'req.file' is empty.

I just wonder what is going wrong? Am I missing something?

**App.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const helpers = require("./helpers");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "image.jpg");
  },
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));

app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: helpers.imageFilter,
  }).single("image");

  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (req.fileValidationError) {
      return res.send(req.fileValidationError);
    } else if (!req.file) {
      return res.send("Please select an image to upload");
    } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }
    res.send(
      `You have uploaded this image: <hr/><img src="${req.file.path}" width="500"><hr /><a href="./">Upload another image</a>`
    );
  });
});
```

**Helpers.js**

```
const imageFilter = function(req, file, cb) {
    // Accept images only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$/)) {
        req.fileValidationError = 'Only image files are allowed!';
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};
exports.imageFilter = imageFilter;
```

**HTML Page**

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It went wrong at the 'const storage'. I filled in the wrong file path. But it strange that the req.file was empty ... Anyway, it works!